# Why Valgrind reports Address 0x522da08 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd?

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm having trouble understanding why Valgrind keeps reporting errors about the allocation of a struct I used.

Here are the following errors I receive:

```
==26932== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==26932== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==26932== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==26932== Command: ./mirsa_genkeys -k sample
==26932== Parent PID: 11465
==26932==
==26932== Invalid write of size 8
==26932==    at 0x108EE9: mr_make_keys (mirsa_lib.c:78)
==26932==    by 0x108BB3: main (mirsa_genkeys.c:44)
==26932==  Address 0x522da08 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==26932==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==26932==    by 0x108EC3: mr_make_keys (mirsa_lib.c:75)
==26932==    by 0x108BB3: main (mirsa_genkeys.c:44)
==26932==
==26932== Invalid read of size 1
==26932==    at 0x4C371F8: mempcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==26932==    by 0x4ECA53B: _IO_default_xsputn (genops.c:404)
==26932==    by 0x4EC7AA2: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1287)
==26932==    by 0x4EBB9E6: fwrite (iofwrite.c:39)
==26932==    by 0x108F1F: mr_make_keys (mirsa_lib.c:81)
==26932==    by 0x108BB3: main (mirsa_genkeys.c:44)
==26932==  Address 0x522da3f is 17 bytes before a block of size 8 alloc'd
==26932==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==26932==    by 0x108ED1: mr_make_keys (mirsa_lib.c:76)
==26932==    by 0x108BB3: main (mirsa_genkeys.c:44)
==26932==
==26932== Invalid read of size 1
==26932==    at 0x4C3720A: mempcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==26932==    by 0x4ECA53B: _IO_default_xsputn (genops.c:404)
==26932==    by 0x4EC7AA2: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1287)
==26932==    by 0x4EBB9E6: fwrite (iofwrite.c:39)
==26932==    by 0x108F1F: mr_make_keys (mirsa_lib.c:81)
==26932==    by 0x108BB3: main (mirsa_genkeys.c:44)
==26932==  Address 0x522da3d is 19 bytes before a block of size 8 alloc'd
==26932==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==26932==    by 0x108ED1: mr_make_keys (mirsa_lib.c:76)
==26932==    by 0x108BB3: main (mirsa_genkeys.c:44)
```

Here's the structure I used for my code:

```
    typedef struct key_s {
    uint64_t key;           
    uint64_t nonce;        
    } key_t;
```

Here's is my code where I attempt to make public and private keys using a set of given numbers.

```
       bool mr_make_keys( uint64_t p, uint64_t q, const char * user){

        struct key_s* public;
        struct key_s* private;
        FILE *public_file;
        FILE *private_file;
        char *public_filename;
        char *private_filename;
        // replace with p
        uint64_t first = 53;
        // replace with q
        uint64_t second = 71;
        uint64_t n= first * second;
        uint64_t phi = (first - 1)*(second - 1);
        uint64_t e;
        uint64_t d;

        int x, y;
        int g = gcdExtended(first, second, &x, &y);
        e = y;
        printf("%d %d gcd(%ld, %ld) = %d\n",x,y ,first, second, g);

        if (n > ULONG_MAX || user == NULL || user[-1] != '\0')
                return false;

        d = (1 + ((e-1) * phi))/e;
        printf("%lu\n", d);
        public_filename = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(user)+5));
        strcpy(public_filename, user);
        strcat(public_filename, ".pub");
        public_file = fopen(public_filename, "w");
        private_filename = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(user)+5));
        strcpy(private_filename, user);
        strcat(private_filename, ".pvt");
        private_file = fopen(private_filename, "w");
        public = malloc( sizeof(struct key_s*));
        private = malloc( sizeof(struct key_s*));
        public->key = e;
        public->nonce = n;
        private->key = d;
        public->key = n;
        fwrite(public,sizeof(uint64_t), sizeof(public),public_file );
        fwrite(private , sizeof(uint64_t), sizeof(private), private_file);
        free(public_filename);
        free(private_filename);
        free(public);
        free(private);
        fclose(public_file);
        fclose(private_file);
        return true;
     }
```

Can someone explain errors to me and how I can fix them?

Comment: You are using `%ld` format spec to output `uint64_t first, second;`. It should be `%llu` but isn't causing the problem. Better still, use `PRIu64`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a problem:

```
    public = malloc( sizeof(struct key_s*));
    public->key = e;
```

You're allocating space for the size of the pointer (8 bytes, on 64 bit), not the size of the structure.

Make a habit of this pattern:

```
    public = malloc(sizeof *public);
```

Comment: After changing it to that. I'm still getting the same error, now it says "Address 0x522dcaf is 17 bytes before a block of size 16 alloc'd".

Comment: The arguments in the `fwrite` calls don't make any sense.